# SyncFusion Grid - replicating Excel's Shift+Enter behaviour

Tags: c#-4.0, syncfusion

I'm trying to make the behaviour of the Enter key in a Syncfusion grid match Excel's behaviour.

I'm able to control the behaviour of the enter key by setting

```
    grid.Model.Options.EnterKeyBehavior = GridDirectionType.Down
```

but I'm struggling to make Shift+Enter make the cell selection move upwards.

Does anyone know how this is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the KeyDown event on the GridControl, check the keys pressed and move the current cell up.

```
void Grid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.KeyCode & Keys.Enter) == Keys.Enter && e.Modifiers == Keys.Shift)
    {
        grid.CurrentCell.Move(GridDirectionType.Up, 1, false);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```